# Force horizontal alignment of nodes to not be affected by lower levels in tikz qtree

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tikz-qtree

I'm trying to create a large hierarchy and have encountered the following problem: Since some of the labels are quite wide, they make nodes in upper levels move out of the way. This means that the tree becomes less readable since I have to shrink it to make it fit on the page. I would therefore like to make, for instance, *value*, *location* and *goal* move closer together, so that *goal* overlaps with *initial location*.

I've tried playing around with (negative) sibling distances for single levels and 
with defining node widths.

I need to use tikz qtree because I need to be able to specify multiple parents.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center},level distance=80pt, sibling distance=20pt}
\Tree 
[.\textit{entity} 
[. \textit{place}
[. \textit{value}\\\textsc{scale}
[. \textit{extent}
[. \textit{amount}
]
]
]
[. \textit{location}\\{\textsc{concreteness} : \textit{concrete}}
[.\node (dest) {\textit{destination}};
]
[.\node (init) {\textit{initial location}};
]
]
[.\node (goal) {\textit{goal}};
]
[.\node (sour) {\textit{source}};
]
]
[.\textit{undergoer}
[. \textit{patient}\\{\textsc{affectedness} : \textit{affected}}
[.\node (resu) {\textit{result}};
[. \textit{product}
]
]
[. \textit{experiencer}\\{\textsc{awareness} : \textit{aware}}
]
]
[. \textit{theme}\\{\textsc{affectedness} : \textit{unaffected}}
]
[. \textit{attribute}
]
]   
[.\textit{actor}
[.\textit{agent}\\{\textsc{intention}}
]
[.\textit{causer}
[. \textit{stimulus}
]
]
[. \textit{instrument}
]
]               
]   
\draw (dest.north) -- (goal.south); 
\draw (init.north) -- (sour.south); 
\draw (resu.north) -- (goal.south); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Feel free to rename this thread since I had a hard time finding a good title.

Comment: `tikz-qtree` isn't very good at packing nodes, since it was designed mainly for linguistics trees. I would redo the tree in `forest`.

Comment: As for your second question, the `align=center` is how the text is formatted (i.e., centred, not left or right aligned). It has nothing to do with aligning the nodes, so I'm not sure what you mean by that part of the question.

Comment: Things that happen when you've stared at your code for too long... I've deleted the question

Comment: @AlanMunn Wasn't Forest designed primarily for linguistics trees, too? I agree it is better at packing nodes and I guess you should know if that doesn't matter to linguists. Just curious ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a version of your tree using `forest`.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest} 
\begin{document}

\begin{forest} for tree={font=\itshape,l sep=1.5cm}
[entity 
[place
[value\\\textsc{scale}
[extent
[amount
]
]
]
[location\\{\textsc{concreteness} : concrete}
[destination,name=dest
]
[initial location,name=init]
]
[goal,name=goal
]
[source,name=sour
]
]
[undergoer
[patient\\{\textsc{affectedness} : affected}
[result,name=resu
[product
]
]
[experiencer\\{\textsc{awareness} : aware}
]
]
[theme\\{\textsc{affectedness} : unaffected}
]
[attribute
]
]
[actor
[agent\\{\textsc{intention}}
]
[causer
[stimulus
]
]
[instrument
]
]
]
\draw (dest.north) -- (goal.south); 
\draw (init.north) -- (sour.south); 
\draw (resu.north) -- (goal.south); 
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]